# How to disable some weights in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Imagine I am trying to fit a model the following way:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x_in=tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=n)
x_out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(m, use_bias=False)(x_in)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=x_in, outputs=x_out)
```

Now the problem is that this will create nxm weights - in my model, however, I want most of the weights to be zero (in fact, only m weights are non-zero); So far, I implemented it by a custom weight constraint function; This however, proved to be extremely slow as the weights that I want to be 0 are nevertheless updated in every iteration and then manually set to 0 which takes a lot of time;

Is there a better way to do it? So a way to say something like "Disable weight w[i,j] whenever i!=(j+1)" such that only these m weights that are not disabled will really be updated in every iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Could the following applied in suitable format solve your problem:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

n=1
m=1

x_in=tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=n)
x_out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(m, use_bias=False,trainable=True)(x_in)
x_out_disabledweights = tf.keras.layers.Dense(m, use_bias=False,trainable=False)(x_in)

model_A = tf.keras.Model(inputs=x_in, outputs=x_out)
model_B = tf.keras.Model(inputs=x_in, outputs=x_out_disabledweights)

print(model_A.summary())
print(model_B.summary())

#by following the idea above, you are able to freeze the weights you want...
weights_before_update=model_B.get_weights()

#fix the weigth to desired value e.g. 0.12345
weights_before_update[0][0][0]=0.12345

#and set the weigths to the model:
model_B.set_weights(weights_before_update)

#and this way you can verify the weight has been updated...
weights_after_update=model_B.get_weights()

print("The weights after manual update...")
print(weights_after_update)
print("And the result of model with test input of one...")
test_result=model_B(np.ones(1))
print(test_result)
```

...please note the possibility to handle trainability of selected layers. You can design several different layers ... having individual characteristics of weights and their features.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer - excuse me if my thinking is a bit slow, so how would that help me? In your case, I have two models, one with n x m trainable weights, and another model without any trainable weights;

Comment: Hi, I'll edit the answer to clarify. Please note by applying the presented procedure you can manually modify the weights you want, according to your need.

Comment: Ah so I basically have let's say n layers with one input, one output and then afterwards, I recombine the entries to one output?

Comment: Hmmm...I think this is a good approach for that. Hard to say exactly ... if you need more info, please describe your need in more detail (perhaps by direct message). But I'm sure you got the point - by utilizing the freedom the mentioned tricks give for you, you can manage many kind of weight manipulations in models.